# Asp.net mvc entity error when use of .SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I wrote a function to handle views in  mysql with entity data model. The column in the database is an int(10), but when I execute this block of code it gives me this error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

If I set the value to 5 manually and set hardcode to 5 into the code block, it doesn't fail on `savechanges`.

```
public static void AddPortfolioView(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new EyeMazingEnt())
        {
            var portfolio = (from a in db.portfolios where a.id.Equals(id) select a).SingleOrDefault();
            if (portfolio != null)
            {
                portfolio.views = 0;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check this `See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`?

Comment: So.. Show the `EntityValidationErrors` property? It will show you exactly what's wrong. I'm putting my money on a discrepancy between your mapping and the actual data you want to insert (think `MaxLength` or `IsRequired`).

Comment: i get this error 10-10-2013 21:18:49: Entity of type "portfolio" in state "Modified" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "description", Error: "The field description must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '255'."

Comment: So, what data are you trying to enter? Use your debugger. It's telling you it wants a string of 255 characters or less. How does your data differ from this?

Comment: i got it now the i had changed the max value off description without updating the model thanks guys sometimes you just need a other set off eyes on it i guess

Comment: Score on the `MaxLength`! ;) Follow the error: it told you one of your properties didn't fit the database's requirements. Your first course of action here should be to look at the additional error messages to figure out what property is causing the issue. After that it's a short walk